# ASP.Net Update Panel timeout

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

how can I fix this?

After a continuous use of the UpdatePanel, it just stops working. I'm using multiple UpdatePanels in one page and all are set in Conditional update.

Comment: Could you please put your code here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more explanation would help.

Anyways, are you updating the UpdatePanel when ever it does a postback?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the time that the browser will wait by setting the `AsyncPostBackTimeout` property on your `ScriptManager` instance in `Page_Load` on the server. You have to set the timeout before the update panel is initially rendered to the browser.

This doesn't affect the server timeout though - you may have an update panel that is waiting for 30 seconds while the server timeout is only 10 seconds, so make sure that they have complementary values for the given page.